# Git Push Including my path directory (BitBucket)

Tags: git, bitbucket

This is my first time to encounter this on bitbucket

As you can see on my screenshot It includes the path (Documents/Project/SampleProjects)
I am on my local project directory (Sample Projects)

[image]

Here's my procedure

```
git init
git add .
git remote add origin my-url.git
git push -u origin master
```

Comment: Which directory did you do all those commands in? Are you sure you were not in the home directory instead of  SampleProjects?

Comment: I am on the SampleProjects Directory

Comment: Is there a .git folder inside SampleProjects? Also, is there a .git folder insider the parent directory of Documents?

Comment: There is no .git on my parent directory, if there is a git on there my repo will messed up.

Comment: I double check my SampleProjects and Yes there is a .git folder

Answer (score 1):

You must execute those command from your project directory

Comment: I execute it on my project directory